# How to refactor media queries wrappers in LESS?

Tags: css, web, less, refactoring, frontend

We have a lot of hover states in our web app and we need to disable all hover states for touch screens. So i decided to wrap all of our hover states in media queries like this :

```
.my-class {

  border-color: blue;

  @media(hover: hover) {
    &:hover {
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, is there a cleaner way to write these media queries wrappers when we have the power of LESS? It will be awful lot of duplication. I am hoping that we could create a small annotation or something like that instead of these wrappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution

```
.hover(@rules) {
  @media(hover: hover) {
    &:hover {
      @rules();
    }
  }
}
```

example usage :

```
.my-class {
  border-color: blue;
  .hover({
    border-color: red;
  });
}
```